# Bootstrap 4 float-right inside .row

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm new to Bootstrap 4 and can't seem to get float-right on a col div working within a row. Here's my code:

```
<div class="row" >
<div class="col-md-8 float-right" style="border: 1px solid red;">
<h3>Five grid tiers</h3>
<p>Hi</p>

</div>
</div>
```

Weirdly it works fine without the row as a parent div, but I'd like to use the row. Am I missing something?

Thanks
:)

Answer (score 66):

row is a flex container in bootstrap-4, to align content in flex-container you need to use `ml-auto` and `mr-auto`.

Here's the example:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row ml-1">
  <div>
     Hello from left
  </div>
  <div class="ml-auto mr-3">
     Hello from right
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the official docuemtation link and example: 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#auto-margins

For cases like when flex container is not being used, you can use `float-right` which is equivalent of `pull-right` in previous versions.

There is also an utility **[Justify Content](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#justify-content)** to change alignment of items in flex container.

Comment: Thank you! "ml-auto mr-3" was the only thing that successfully "floated" my content inside the div, inside a row, to the right

Comment: `ml-auto` is the best practice to float right. Thank you!

Comment: Just in case someone tries this while using bootstrap 5 -> `ml-auto` got changed to `ms-auto` and `mr-auto` to `me-auto`

Answer (score 21):

Bootstrap 4 has incorporated Flexbox for their layouts. You can get your desired result by adding the class 'justify-content-end' to the parent container.

```html
<div class="row justify-content-end" >
  <div class="col-md-8" style="border: 1px solid red;">
    <h3>Five grid tiers</h3>
    <p>Hi</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to learn the basics of Flexbox, I recommend checking out this quick and fun tutorial: http://flexboxfroggy.com/. It's a great system, though it is not supported in Legacy IE (IE 9 and earlier).

Answer (score 11):

Standing to [bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/#auto-margins) you should use `ml-auto` class on the col you want to be placed on the right.

In this way (look at the example) you can have only the item you want on the right, while all the other cols will still be on the natural flow (on the left).

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3 border border-primary">
      One 
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 border border-primary">
      Two
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 border border-success ml-auto">
      Three
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

What you could try:

```
<div class="row float-right">
    <div class="col-md-8 float-right" style="border: 1px solid red;">
        <h3>Five grid tiers</h3>
        <p>Hi</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you are using `bootstrap 3`, you will have to use `pull-right` instead of `float-right`.

Answer (score 3):

Soren is correct.  Bootstrap 4 uses flex box.  Floats stuck!  Try to forget them!

```
<div class="row justify-content-end">
  <div class="col-4"> One of two columns </div>
  <div class="col-4"> One of two columns </div>
</div>
```

Pull-right is a bootstrap 3 tag.

Comment: Sage answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If all you want is to "pull" the column to the right, you can use an "offset". Since you use `col-md-8`, add `offset-md-4`.

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-4" style="border: 1px solid red;">
    <h3>Five grid tiers</h3>
    <p>Hi</p>

  </div>
</div>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.right-searchbox-content {
     margin-left: auto !important;
}

.right-searchbox {
    float: right !important;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
<div class="row">
<div class="right-searchbox-content">
    <div class="right-searchbox">
        <div class="header">
            <span>my search:</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This code snippet helped me to position the *Create Account* button at the right.

```
<div class="row justify-content-end">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <a asp-action="AddAccount" class="btn btn-secondary w-100">
        <i class="fas fa-backward"></i>Create Account</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the **float-right** class in a div inside **col-md-8** div, then put your content inside this div.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8" style="border: 1px solid red;">
        <!-- new div -->
        <div class="float-right">
           <!-- this content will be align to right -->
           <h3>Five grid tiers</h3>
           <p>Hi</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using "Text-Right" or center/left inside a column.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        Left Text
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 text-right">
        Right Text
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -4):

For cshtml pages with bootstrap use below

@Html.ActionLink("Back","Index","Controller",null, new { @class="btn btn-warning"})

    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", "Controller", null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary " })

Answer (score -4):

Bootstrap 4 uses flexbox. You can fix this by replacing 'justify-content-end' instead of 'float-right'.

```
<div class="row" >
    <div class="col-md-8 justify-content-end" style="border: 1px solid red;">
      <h3>Five grid tiers</h3>
      <p>Hi</p>    
    </div>
</div>
```